# Trying to sort or order query results with PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to sort ascending event listings based on the `start_date`. However, I cannot figure out where to put the line

```
sortBY('start_time', 'asc')
```

or

```
orderBy('start_date', 'asc')
```

Here's my complete code:

```
@if(!empty($events) && $events->count() > 0)
    @foreach($events as $event)
        @if($event->is_published)
            <div class="event-row">
                <div style="display: table-cell; width: 20%;">
                    @if($event->uploads->count() > 0)
                        <img src="{!! $event->uploads->reverse()->first()->url !!}" alt="" title="" width="150"
                             height="150">
                    @endif
                </div>
                <div style="display: table-cell; width: 80%; vertical-align: top;">
                    <div>
                        <h3 style="margin-top: 3px; margin-bottom: 3px;">{!! $event->name !!}</h3><br/>
                        @if($event->start_time > 0)
                            <small style="font-size: 14px;">
                                {!! $event->start_time !!} - {!! $event->end_time !!}
                            </small>
                        @endif
                        <p style="margin-top: 6px; margin-bottom: 3px;">{!! $event->description !!}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endif
    @endforeach
@else
    Sorry, there are no events.
@endif
```

I found what I believe to be the query:

```
namespace App\Models\General;

use App\Models\System\Upload;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * Class Session
 * package App.
 */
class Event extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'description', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'is_published'];

    public function uploads()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Upload::class, 'uploadable');
    }
}
```

Is this the query?

Comment: Does Laravel really use the suppression operator like this?

Comment: You put the `orderBy` on the Query builder code. Not in the page template

Comment: It must be on your controller then call it to your view blade.

Comment: I am a complete noob when it comes to Laravel. Where would I find the Query Builder code?

Comment: You can call `sortBy()` on a collection with just the column as an argument and it'll default to `asc`. It would be something like `$events->sortBy('start_date')->all()`

Comment: Can you post the source code of the controller method that displays this view?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton It's used for the Blade template controls

Comment: You can change the model `uploads()` relation if this is what you need permanently, if not better to do it in your controller `return $this->morphMany(Upload::class, 'uploadable')->orderBy('start_date', 'asc');`

Answer (score 0):

Be careful using [dynamic properties](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#dynamic-properties) in blade files.  You don't want your presentation layer accidentally executing SQL queries.

That said, [$builder->orderBy()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) applies the sorting to the SQL query.  When you do `$builder->get()` what you get back is [Eloquent's child-class](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-collections) of [Support\Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-sortby).  And Support\Collections has a `sortBy()` method that makes Php perform the sorting.

Whenever possible, make SQL do the work.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$events->orderBy('start_date', 'asc')->get()
```

So your foreach will look like:

```
@foreach($events->orderBy('start_date', 'asc')->get() as $event)
```

**Note** if you order in your controller then use:

```
@foreach($events as $event)
```

And your final snippet(depending on where you ordered):

```
@if(!empty($events) && $events->count() > 0)
@foreach($events as $event)
    @if($event->is_published)
        <div class="event-row">
            <div style="display: table-cell; width: 20%;">
                @if($event->uploads->count() > 0)
                    <img src="{!! $event->uploads->reverse()->first()->url !!}" alt="" title="" width="150"
                         height="150">
                @endif
            </div>
            <div style="display: table-cell; width: 80%; vertical-align: top;">
                <div>
                    <h3 style="margin-top: 3px; margin-bottom: 3px;">{!! $event->name !!}</h3><br/>
                    @if($event->start_time > 0)
                      <small style="font-size: 14px;">
                          {!! $event->start_time !!} - {!! $event->end_time !!}
                      </small>
                    @endif
                    <p style="margin-top: 6px; margin-bottom: 3px;">{!! $event->description !!}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endif
@endforeach
@else
    Sorry, there are no events.
@endif
```

Assuming your controller looks like:

```
use App\Models\General\Event;
....
class EventsController extends \Illuminate\Routing\Controller
{
     public function index()
     {
         return view('events', [
             'events' => Event::orderBy('start_date', 'asc')->get()
         ]);
     }
}
```

Comment: Using your final snippet created a long list of errors. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes. My guess is that you have already run your query. Move the `orderBy('start_date', 'asc')->get()` to wherever this query is being executed. `Event::orderBy('start_date', 'asc')->get()` assuming your model is named Event.

Comment: As I am woefully unfamiliar with Laravel, I do not know where the query is being executed. Any guidance in that regard?

Comment: If you're calling `Event::orderBy(...)->get()` in your controller, then there's no reason to call `$events->orderBy(...)->get()` in your `.blade.php` file. I'd be surprised if that worked without an error (I don't think `orderBy()` is available on a `Collection`, which is what `$events` would be in your `.blade.php` file)

Comment: @adam see my revised question.

Comment: @OuterData Do you have `Event:::all()` anywhere in your code?